# Connection to HBase with Simba ODBC driver

Tags: odbc, tableau-api, simba

I always get this error for connecting to HBase with Simba ODBC driver:

> Failure: [Simba][HBase] (20) Error with HTTP API: Couldn't connect to server.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the host name , port number & Vnet you have used?

Comment: I'm using 192.168.180.136 for host and 60010 for port number sir.

Comment: Have you enabled the Stargate REST interface? The driver communicates with this and you will need to point it there before a connection can be made.